# How do I get a cube having different textured image on each face of cube in glkit?

Tags: opengl-es, ios6, opengl-es-2.0, game-physics, glkit

I am developing a game in which I have to shake a dice to get number. I am using glkit to make a cube and texturing that cube by GLKBaseEffect. Well ! I want a cube having diffrent textured images on each faces so that it can simulates a dice. I want each faces of cube show different dice image like one face show number 1 another face show number two and so on.

I am pasting my code here.

```
- (void)setupGL {

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    
self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                          GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft, 
                          nil];

NSError * error;    
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tile_floor" ofType:@"png"];
GLKTextureInfo * info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
if (info == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
self.effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;

// draw one texture per side



// New lines
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

// Old stuff
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// New lines (were previously in draw)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);        
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Color));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));

// New line
glBindVertexArrayOES(0); 
}
```

and calling draw elements method from here in drawInRects

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
[self.effect prepareToDraw];
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you solved this? If you have solved can you explain me how you did? you can post it as an answer though!!

Comment: Well!! i didn't get any solution to achieve this using GLKit but got a solution directly using openGL commands.You only have to load six different texture and render it in same frame buffer.I used core Graphics to create bitmaps of these six textures and sent to openGL Land for rendering.I will achieve the same with GLKit soon and also will post here. @Nicol Bolas

Answer (score 1):

GLKit has a limited number of textures allowed (2, I think), so you'll need what's called a texture-map.  Basically, you set up a texture like this:

```
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d ...
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
a a a a a a a a b b b b b b b b c c c c c c c c d d d d d d d d
```

And then you set your texture coordinates for each vertex to point to the sub-portion of the texture that you want to use.

*NOTE*: Even if GLKit supported more textures, as many OpenGL implementations do, this method is MUCH faster than loading a gazillion textures and switching them all the time.  `glBind()` is a relatively slow operation.

Also note: Things are more efficient if your texture image sides are powers of 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...)  It's ok to have blank (unused) spots in your texture image.  I typically put a big red blotch in the unused part, so I can tell if it inadvertently shows up on anything.

So your dice-texture might be, say, 32px tall, and 512 (32*8) wide, but you only use the first 192 (32*6) of it and have a set of six 32x32 textures all in one image.

Comment: Unless for some reason you need six separate texture resources on the GPU, this is your best plan -- you can get the whole cube in one pair of Bind and Draw calls. (With the Bind call handled for you by `GLKBaseEffect`.) You don't need to have multiple draw calls or multiple texture resources.

Answer (score 0):

I do this by layering, or having more objects. So, a cube, and then two squares that are just barely on the skin of the cube. If the cube is 2 x 2 x 2, just make the picture vertex 2.01, and so it is like cake icing

So you are not texturing the cube, you are adding more objects. Here is a video example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lh2Zc8kHFbU&list=UUu5WfUbKdhLCW9aPq3WZsNA